# How to fix "Proxy error: Could not proxy request from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/" when using socket.io for real-time chat

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I have been trying to implement chat module in my app. I have little experience in MERN full stack and it is my first time working with socket.io. But whenever I try to create a chat room, it throws an error and doesn't create any chat room.

I have tried to search for solutions but couldn't find any.

(I am really Sorry if it's a lot of code, I shortened it as much as possible but I wasn't sure which parts would be relevant to the question).

```
class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false,
      chatLists: []
    };

    //this.socket = io("localhost:8080");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
    //   this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    // }
    axios.get(`/chats/list`).then(res => {
      const chatLists = res.data;
      this.setState({ chatLists });
    });
  }

  sendChatId(i) {
    return <ChatDetail chatId={i} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Chat">
        {/* <AppNavbar /> */}
        <CreateRoom />
        <hr />
        <h3>Chat Room List</h3>
        <Router>
          <ListGroup>
            {this.state.chatLists.map(chatList => (
              <ListGroupItem tag="a" key={chatList._id}>
                <Link to={`/chatDetail`}>
                  {chatList.roomTitle}
                  {this.sendChatId(chatList._id)}
                </Link>
                <Route path={`/chatDetail`} component={ChatDetail} />
              </ListGroupItem>
            ))}
          </ListGroup>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Chat.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  //errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
  //errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(Chat));
```

I have 3 order files named "ChatDetails.js", "ChatList.js"and "CreateRoom.js" for which idk if I have to post the code here or not.

This is the model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Chat Schema
const ChatSchema = new Schema({
  roomTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = Chat = mongoose.model("Chat", ChatSchema);

//const Chat =  module.exports = mongoose.model('Chat', ChatSchema);

module.exports.addChatRoom = function(newChat, callback) {
  newChat.save(callback);
};
```

Model for chat details

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//const config = require('../config/database');

// Chat Detail Schema
const ChatDetailSchema = new Schema({
  chatMsg: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  msgBy: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  chatId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Chat",
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = ChatDetail = mongoose.model("ChatDetail", ChatDetailSchema);

//const ChatDetail =  module.exports = mongoose.model('ChatDetail', ChatDetailSchema);

module.exports.addChatMsg = function(newMsg, callback) {
  newMsg.save(callback);
};
```

And chat routes

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
//const config = require('../../config/database');
const Chat = require("../../models/Chat");
const ChatDetail = require("../../models/ChatDetail");
const http = require("http").Server(express);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

//const express = require("express");
//const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");

// Post model
//const Post = require("../../models/Post");
// Profile model
//const Profile = require("../../models/Profile");

// get list of all chat room list
/**
 * @route   GET api/chats/list
 * @desc    Get all chatrooms list
 */
router.get("/list", (req, res, next) => {
  Chat.find()
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(chats => res.json(chats));
});

/**
 * @route   POST api/chats/create
 * @desc    Create a new chat room
 * @param   {String} roomTitle
 * @param   {String} createdBy
 */
router.post("/create", (req, res) => {
  let newChat = new Chat({
    roomTitle: req.body.roomTitle,
    createdBy: req.body.createdBy
  });

  Chat.addChatRoom(newChat, (err, chat) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        msg: "Can not create Chat room"
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        msg: "Successfully created a chat room"
      });
    }
  });
});

/**
 * @route   GET api/chats/detail/:id
 * @desc    Get Chat Details
 * @param   {String} chatId
 */
router.get("/detail/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  const chatId = req.params.id;
  Chat.findById(chatId)
    .then(function(chat) {
      if (chat) {
        const queryForMsgs = ChatDetail.find();
        queryForMsgs.where("chatId", chatId);
        queryForMsgs.populate("chatId");
        queryForMsgs.exec(function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            res.json("No chat msgs here" + err);
          } else {
            res.json(result);
          }
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
});

/**
 * @route   POST api/chats/addMsg/:id
 * @desc    Add new chat msg with chatRoom Id, username, message
 * @param   {String} chatId
 */
router.post("/addMsg/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  const chatId = req.params.id;
  let newMsg = new ChatDetail({
    chatId: chatId,
    chatMsg: req.body.chatMsg,
    msgBy: req.body.msgBy
  });

  ChatDetail.addChatMsg(newMsg, (err, chatMsgs) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        msg: "No msg send"
      });
    } else {
      // res.json ({success: true, msg: 'Successfully Send a msg'});
      io.on("connection", function(socket) {
        console.log("A New msg send....");
        socket.on("getMsgBy", function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          socket.emit("msgData", { msgBy: data });
        });

        socket.on("msgToAll", function(data) {
          //Send message to everyone
          io.sockets.emit("newmsg", data);
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

/**
 * Delete chat msg from chat detail
 * @route   DELETE api/chats/delete/:id
 * @desc    Delete A chat message
 * @param   {String} chatMsgId
 * @return  {Boolean}
 */
router.delete("/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
  const chatMsgId = req.params.id;
  ChatDetail.findById(chatMsgId)
    .then(chat => chat.remove().then(() => res.json({ success: true })))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
});

/**
 * @route  POST api/chats/update/:id
 * @desc   Update chat Messages
 * @param   {String} chatMsgId
 */
router.post("update/:id", (req, res) => {
  const chatMsgId = req.params.id;
  ChatDetail.findById(chatMsgId).exec(function(err, result) {
    result.set({
      chatMsg: req.body.chatMsg,
      msgBy: req.body.msgBy
    });
    result.save(function(err, newResult) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        io.on("connection", function(socket) {
          console.log("Msg updates....");
          socket.on("getMsgBy", function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit("msgData", { msgBy: data });
          });

          socket.on("msgToAll", function(data) {
            //Send message to everyone
            io.sockets.emit("newmsg", data);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
});

// test routes
router.get("/test", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("This route works fine");
});

module.exports = router;
```

And on entry point of app, server.js

```
// Initialize socket.io
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

// Use Routes
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use("/api/chats", chats);
app.use("/api/profile", profile);
app.use("/api/posts", posts);

//Whenever someone connects this gets executed
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  console.log("A user connected..........");

  //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
  socket.on("disconnect", function() {
    console.log("A user disconnected........");
  });
});

userChat = [];
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  console.log("A user connected");
  socket.on("setMsgBy", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // check this msgBy in chatroom of database
    userChat.push(data);
    socket.emit("userSet", { msgBy: data });
  });

  socket.on("msg", function(data) {
    //Send message to everyone
    io.sockets.emit("newmsg", data);
  });
});
```

I expect the user to input the chat room name and his name to get on a front end.

Comment: Does your project have a package.json you could post?

Comment: Yes sure I have. Should I post front-end react package.json or back-end package.json?

Comment: Post both of them. I just want to look to see if there are any references to localhost or configuration to which IP should be used to connect to the server.

Comment: Yes the reference is on React client side.   `code`{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6","socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
} `code`

Comment: Ok, so try to change localhost to your local IP. Like "192.54.53.45:5000". So if you're on a windows machine - go to your command prompt and type 'ipconfig' to show all your local connection types. Look for the IPV4 Address with the Default Gateway filled in below it. If you're on Mac or Linux try 'ipconfig', 'ifconfig', 'iwconfig', or Google.

Comment: should I change the ip address on both front end and back end?

Comment: it didn't work. I don't know if I did it right but it didn't let the front end communicate with the back end.

Comment: Yes change them both to the same thing. The one on the back end tells the server what to listen for, and the front end what to connect to.

Comment: I tried to change it in server.js file but it gave a syntax error. I did change the front-end but it didn't work.